# How to halt the execution a Servlet WebApp from a ContextListener?

Tags: java, tomcat, servlets

I have a java web application, that has a very strict security requirement. on Start-up it tries to configure the web container to force it use SSL session id to establish the http session id. If it fails in this configuration I want the app to stop and not process an request. I can use `System.exit()` as I am doing in the sample below, but I am wondering if there is a nice way to do this without killing the JVM. Also a security manager can get in the way of `System.exit()`

I am using tomcat 7.

```
public class SessionTrackingModeListener implements ServletContextListener
{
    @Override
    public void contextInitialized(ServletContextEvent event)
    {
        try
        {
            ServletContext context = event.getServletContext();
            EnumSet<SessionTrackingMode> modes = EnumSet.of(SessionTrackingMode.SSL);
                context.setSessionTrackingModes(modes);
                    System.out.println("SSL based Session tracking enabled");
        } catch (Exception e)
        {
            System.err.println("Unable to setup SSL based session tracking");
            e.printStackTrace();
            System.exit(1);

           // Question How do I get the container to not start the app without using exit?
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void contextDestroyed(ServletContextEvent event)
    {
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

First of all I think it is not a good idea to use

```
System.exit(1)
```

in a servlet environment, since some web containers may use a security manager to prevent your webapp to kill the entire server.

The servlet spec is not strict about what happens when you throw a runtime exception in the contextInitialized function. In my experience the servlet containers abort the startup of the webapp, but again it may depend on your container so you should test it.
If you are using plain old servlets it maybe a good choice to create a ServletFilter which checks whether the security constraints are ok or redirect the request to an error page.

Answer (score 1):

Would you please explain more about  "want the app to stop and not process an request".You mean yours web application OR web container.Do you want to show some human readable message on web application when there is some problem in container to user ?.As when there is exception the tomcat does not get started start.You have to start it again .

Comment: just my web app, I don't any requests directed at the web app at all, as far as the outside world goes the app should not respond to any requests, the container should return 404.

Comment: Are you using any framework ?In spring framework it is handled by  default showing 404 when there is error in startup.See this
http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.1.x/spring-framework-reference/html/mvc.html

Comment: The app still starts, and spring does not know about the other context listeners and errors they might throw, so it just happily moves along.

Comment: In  exception you can throw the custom exception in SessionTrackingModeListener class.See this one 
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13487672/spring-mvc-controller-and-exception-handling/15829306#15829306.That custom exception for 404 error